# Best practice to store and access data objects in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a json endpoint that returns a list of objects. The first view is a list with just some basic info but if you select an item I want to show more details. Should I just construct and object in my factory and have another method to get the details? so

```
getItems() // returns list data
getItem(id)// goes through the object already retrieved and returns just the data?
```

I don't want to hit the server again for each item but I'm not sure of the best way to do this in Angular. It doesn't appear the Model is made for this in Angular.

Also, assuming Item has additional information that I may need to make another server request. What's the best way to store this locally so if I already fetches these details once I don't need to get it again?

Comment: Use a service. However, your questions appears to me to be off-topic for SO, as it entails discussion and is primarily based on opinion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exchange data between 2 controllers, you can use a provider

```
App.provider('Data', function() {

//Properties declaration
this.info = '';
//Setters
this.setInfo = function(info) {
    this.info = info;
};
//Getters
this.getInfo = function() {
    return this.info;
};
```

controller 1

```
App.controller(
    'controller1',
    ['$scope', 'Data',
        function($scope, Data) { Data.setInfo('here you put what you want') }]);
```

controller which get back information

```
App.controller(
    'controller2',
    ['$scope', 'Data',
        function($scope, Data) { Data.getInfo() }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

More likely, you'll want to use either a factory or a service:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#factory

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#service

In both cases, you provide a function which Angular will call once and store the return reference, then provide that reference to any controller or other Angular-managed object that requests it. The difference between a factory and service is that a **service** function is expected to be a **constructor function** (it's called using the "new" keyword) whereas a **factory** is a just invoked as a **regular function**.